# Change text depending on the size of the array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following scope and if this is greater than 5, I'd like to display something like 'more than ten items' otherwise it will just list the items in a human readable list

```
<span class="bold-words">{{rule.words.join(', ')}}</span>
```

What is the correct AngularJS way to do this?

e.g so it would show like below

```
// less than 5 
Your list is "peas, fruit, tea"
// more than 5
Your list is greater than 5 items
```

Comment: use ng-if https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with ternary operator

```
<span class="bold-words">Your list is {{ rule.words.length > 5 ? 'greater than 5 items' : rule.words.join(', ') }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this ...

```
 <span class="bold-words">Your list is {{(rule.words.length>5)?'greater than 5 item':(rule.words.join(', '))}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a filter like `{{ rule.words | beautifier:5 }}` So you can use it on different cases and can modify your output at will. See the snippet for a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('bar', []);
app.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.bar = ['asdasd', 'egeg', 'hjgkj', 'adaa'];
});
app.filter('beautifier', function() {
    return function(input, count) {
        var output;

        if (input.length > count) {
            output = 'Your list is greater than ' + count +' items.';
        } else {
            output = 'Your list is "' + input.join('", "') + '"';
        }

        return output;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="bar">
  <div ng-controller="foo">
    <p>{{ bar | beautifier:5 }}</p>
    <p>{{ bar | beautifier:3 }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```